# C++ - one function makes others malfunction

Tags: c++

Here is my task:

Write class Word which has:

1. pointer on array of characters
2. constructors and destructors
3. function to read word
4. function to check if character which is passed to it as argument occurs in word and return position of occurance
5. function to check which of two words has more occurances of number 10 and to return that number of occurances

Here is my solution. I compiled it without errors but it doesn't work as it shoud.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Word
  {
    private:
       char *content;
       int length;
    public:
       Word();
       Word(char *);
       ~Word();
       void print_content(void);
       int check_character(char);
       friend int check_number(Word,Word);
  };


Word::Word()
  {
  }

Word::Word(char *n)
  {
    length=strlen(n);
    content=new char [length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
      {
         content[i]=n[i];
      }
  }


Word::~Word()
  {
    delete content;
  }


void Word::print_content(void)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
      {
        cout<<""<<content[i];
      }
  }


int Word::check_character(char a)
  {
    int position=0;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
      {
         if(content[i]==a)
          {
            position=i+1;
          }
      }
    if(position>0)
      {
        return position;
      }
    else return 0;
  }


int check_number(Word n,Word m)
  {
    int counter_n=0;
    int counter_m=0;
    for(int i=1;i<n.length;i++)
      {
        if((n.content[i-1]=='1')&&(n.content[i]=='0'))
          {
            counter_n=counter_n+1;
          }
      }
    for(int i=1;i<m.length;i++)
      {
        if((m.content[i-1]=='1')&&(m.content[i]=='0'))
          {
            counter_m=counter_m+1;
          }
      }
    if(counter_n>counter_m)
      { 
        return counter_n;
      }
    else if(counter_n<counter_m)
      {
        return counter_m;
      }
    else return 0;
  }


int main()
  {
    char characters1[]="qwerty10",*p1,*p2;
    char characters2[]="stackoverflow101010";
    p1=characters1;
    p2=characters2;
    Word first(p1);
    Word second(p2);
    cout<<""<<first.check_character('q')<<endl;
    cout<<""<<second.check_character('f')<<endl;

    //cout<<""<<check_number(first,second)<<endl; 

    first.print_content();
    second.print_content();
  }
```

Function check_number(first,second) for some reason makes other functions to work incorrectly, if you call it by removing "//" you will see that first.print_content() and second.print_content() don't give us correct result. Or if function first.check_character('r') is first called, second.check_character('j') second called and then check_number(first,second), then two firsly called functions don't work.
What's reason for this strange behaviour?

Comment: [You need to read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). You're epically violating the Rule of Three. And `delete content;` is wrong; it should be `delete [] content;` (and in practice `content` should be `std::string` to avoid all this in the first place).

Comment: Ever heard of [Indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_(typesetting)) ?

Comment: @Arun A.S, I hope it is easier to read now.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I replaced delete content with delete [] content. I read your link but I'm not sure I understand it :(  I'm new in programming world :)

Comment: @etf - I rolled back your edit. You're not supposed to fix the poster's code - otherwise anyone else who comes along isn't looking at the same code as those who have already attempted to work on the question. Changing indentation, improving readability - those are OK - but don't "fix" bugs in the question. If you want to tell them how to fix things, post an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis, code I originally posted is changed. For example, in my original code I posted here there is line "content[i]=n[i];" but I saw here "= content=n;". How it is possible?

Comment: There are also other things which are not in my original code I posted here.

Comment: @BobJarvis It's rare enough that new users respond to feedback to correct issues in their posts.  So when one gets feedback about indentation and fixes it themselves...then shows they've had trouble with figuring out the pasting mechanics on StackOverflow (corrects those issues that are obviously some kind of "from the IDE to the web box issue" when they said compilation wasn't their problem), you reverting them fixing pasting errors when there are no answers is not at all appropriate.  Thanks.

Comment: @HostileFork, I got suggestion that I should fix indentation and I did it, but that's everything I did! I have no idea how "content[i]=n[i];" from my original code changed to "= content=n;" (in constructor), or my original "if((m.content[i-1]=='1')&&(m.content[i]=='0'))" to "if((m.content[i-1]=='1')&&(m.content=='0'))" (check_number function) etc.

Comment: @etf I'm not the one who thinks your correction was any kind of problem...quite the opposite!  Whatever the glitch was that got your array indices here, just keep an eye out next time and check.  *(It's always a good idea to read your question every time--including code--top to bottom in the preview before clicking post.)*  Good luck and keep studying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Word` objects are passed by copy to `check_number`, but you did not define the copy constructor. So default one is used by the compiler and  this one copies pointer (`char* content`). Temporary objects passed to the function are pointing to data created `first` and `second` in the main function...upon deletion (temprary objects are deleted after the function is called), they delete the pointers, so `first` and `second` objects are pointing to deleted memory. You have undetermined behaviour here, this explains side effects you experienced.

Passing objects by reference to `check_number` is an easy way to fix your problem. Here is a working code (including many fixes because you did not access arrays correctly):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Word
  {
    private:
       char *content;
       int length;
    public:
       Word();
       Word(char *);
       ~Word();
       void print_content(void);
       int check_character(char);
       friend int check_number(const Word&,const Word&); // changed here
  };


Word::Word()
  {
  }

Word::Word(char *n)
  {
    length=strlen(n);
    content=new char [length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
      {
        content[i]=n[i]; // changed here
      }
  }


Word::~Word()
  {
    delete [] content; // changed here
  }


void Word::print_content(void)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
      {
        cout<<""<<content[i]; // changed here
      }
  }


int Word::check_character(char a)
  {
    int position=0;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
      {
         if(content[i]==a) // changed here
          {
            position=i+1;
          }
      }
    if(position>0)
      {
        return position;
      }
    else return 0;
  }


int check_number( const Word& n, const Word& m)// changed here
  { 
    int counter_n=0;
    int counter_m=0;
    for(int i=1;i<n.length;i++)
      {
        if((n.content[i-1]=='1')&&(n.content[i]=='0')) // changed here
          {
            counter_n=counter_n+1;
          }
      }
    for(int i=1;i<m.length;i++)
      {
        if((m.content[i-1]=='1')&&(m.content[i]=='0')) // changed here
          {
            counter_m=counter_m+1;
          }
      }
    if(counter_n>counter_m)
      { 
        return counter_n;
      }
    else if(counter_n<counter_m)
      {
        return counter_m;
      }
    else return 0;
  }


int main()
  {
    char characters1[]="qwerty10",*p1,*p2;
    char characters2[]="stackoverflow101010";
    p1=characters1;
    p2=characters2;
    Word first(p1);
    Word second(p2);
    cout<<""<<first.check_character('q')<<endl;
    cout<<""<<second.check_character('f')<<endl;

    cout<<""<<check_number(first,second)<<endl; 

    first.print_content();
    second.print_content();
  }
```

This outputs:

```
1
10
3
qwerty10stackoverflow101010
```

Declaring a copy constructor is another way to fix the problem:

```
Word( const Wodr& word ) :
    length( word.length ),
    content( new char[word.length] )
{
    memcpy( content, word.content, word.length );
}
```

That would be less efficient than passing objects by const reference, but would make your code safer (it's good to always declare copy constructor to prevent bug you experienced here).

Finally, if you are lazy, you can also declare the copy constructor as private, to prevent compiler to copy objects, just declare it, don't impelment it:

```
class Word
{
   ....
private:
    Word( const Word& word ); // this makes argument passed by copy impossible.
};
```

Then, compiler will not let you call check_number.